# Why are ImageMagick and Shotwell both pre-installed?

Tags: shotwell, imagemagick

Their jobs are pretty much the same right? I want to uninstall useless programs. But I fear I may lose important things. I have GIMP and Inkscape installed though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Their jobs are pretty much the same right?

Shotwell is an organizing tool for photo's. Imagemagick lets you manipulate images I dare you to use shotwell on commandline to convert an image from a GIF to a PNG ;-)

From the Ubuntu apps directory:

[**Shotwell**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shotwell/) is a digital photo organizer designed for the GNOME desktop environment. It allows you to import photos from disk or camera, organize them in various ways, view them in full-window or fullscreen mode, and export them to share with others. It is able to manage a lot of different image formats, also including raw CR2 files.

[**ImageMagick**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/imagemagick/) is a software suite to create, edit, and compose bitmap images. It can read, convert and write images in a variety of formats (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF. Use ImageMagick to translate, flip, mirror, rotate, scale, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves. All manipulations can be achieved through shell commands as well as through an X11 graphical interface (display).

Comment: So if I got GIMP, a better bitmap editor, then I can comfortably remove IM?